# Using CRTP to create Eigen matrix

Tags: c++, templates, eigen, crtp

I have a hierarchy of classes which contain some Eigen matrices as members but their size depends on the derived class. I want to be able to declare the matrices in the base class but have the size being used from the derived class. I thought I could use CRTP for this but I am not sure I am using it correctly. Here is the code I tried

```
template<typename T>
class Base {
public:
    const int matSize = static_cast(T*)(this)->_matSize;
    Eigen::Matrix<int, matSize, mastSize> Mat = Eigen::Matrix<int, matSize, matSize>::Zero();

    virtual void print() { std::cout << Mat << std::endl; };
};

class Derived1 : public Base<Derived1>{
public:
    const int _matSize = 3;
};

class Derived2 : public Base<Derived2>{
public:
    const int _matSize = 4;
};

int main(){
    Derived1 d1;
    d1.print();   // print a 3x3 zero matrix

    Derived2 d2;
    d2.print();   // print a 4x4 zero matrix

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

However, this doesn't work. Is there a way to achieve something like this?

Edit:

The main reason for doing above is that I have functions that do some matrix algebra which would work regardless of the size. So I would like to be able to call that function on objects of different derived classes and just be able to use the same function instead of having separate functions for each matrix size.

Also to have an interface that the any object of type Base will have a matrix Mat whose size will depend on which derived class of Base it was created from.

Comment: You have to learn the keyword constexpr.

Comment: Can you please elaborate or give a reference example? I looked around for usage of constexpr in this context but perhaps I don't understand constexpr very well.

Comment: I'm curious as to why you are using CRTP in this way. The only thing you are providing is the matrix size, which is a template parameter of `Eigen::Matrix` you could simply declare `d1` as `Eigen::Matrix<int,3,3>::Zero()`. Have you left something out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in my comment there really is no reason to use CRTP for just what you have indicated, but if you are set on this pattern for some other reason something like the following should work (I don't have `Eigen::Matrix` available so I stubbed out the necessary interface for the compiler):

```
#include <iostream>

namespace Eigen {
    template<typename T, int W, int H>
    class Matrix {
    public:
        static Matrix<T,W,H> Zero() {
            return Matrix<T, W, H>{};
        }

        std::ostream &print_on(std::ostream &strm) const {
            return strm;
        }
    };
}

template <typename T, int W, int H>
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &strm, Eigen::Matrix<T,W,H> const &matrix) {
    return matrix.print_on(strm);
}

template<typename T, int S>
class Base {
public:
    Eigen::Matrix<int, S, S> Mat = Eigen::Matrix<int, S, S>::Zero();

    virtual void print() { std::cout << Mat << std::endl; };
};

class Derived1 : public Base<Derived1,3>{
public:
};

class Derived2 : public Base<Derived2,4>{
public:
};

template <int Size>
class AdvertisingDerived : public Base<AdvertisingDerived<Size>,Size> {
public:
    constexpr static int matrixSize = Size;
};

int main(){
    Derived1 d1;
    d1.print();   // print a 3x3 zero matrix

    Derived2 d2;
    d2.print();   // print a 4x4 zero matrix

    AdvertisingDerived<3> ad1;

    AdvertisingDerived<4> ad2;

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That works well! However, I wanted to be able to have the derived class "advertise" the matrix size as perhaps a `static const int matrixSize = 3`  and then use that in the template parameter as `class Derived1 : public Base<Derived1, Derived1::matrixSize>`. But this gives me a compiler error `invalid template argument for base, expected compile-time expression`.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand why I get that error. Even though the variable `matrixSize` is a static variable, it is not available to the compiler during compile time when creating the class. I also understand why you thought CRTP was unnecessary. I guess I was just trying some way of having the matrix size in the derived class and using that to determine the size of the matrix in the base class.

Comment: @Bilentor And yes you have to remember the difference between compile time programming and run time programming when working with templates, especially as you start to use more sophisticated techniques. What you can do with template meta programming is well worth the effort though.

Comment: Thanks for the patient explanations. I am new to C++ coming from Python/Haskell so still getting used to the concepts.

Answer (score 2):

You can't access members of `Derived1` (from anywhere outside `Derived1`) until it is fully defined. The usual workaround to this issue is to use some sort of traits class:

```
template<class D>
struct MyTraits;

template<typename T>
class Base {
public:
    static const int matSize = MyTraits<T>::_matSize;
    Eigen::Matrix<int, matSize, matSize> Mat = Eigen::Matrix<int, matSize, matSize>::Zero();

    virtual void print() { std::cout << Mat << std::endl; };
};

class Derived1;
template<>
struct MyTraits<Derived1> {static const int _matSize = 3;};

class Derived1 : public Base<Derived1>{
public:
};
```

Godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/pf-B_R

Especially, if `Derived1` itself is a class template, the traits would be (partially) templated as well. Whether this makes sense in your case is hard to tell from the code you provided.

Btw: There should be no need to make `Base::print()` `virtual`. The main point of static polymorphism is to avoid dynamic polymorphism.